# Uploading public video to facebook and retrieving video id

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, mobile, sdk

I want to expand my current IOS applicaiton by allowing users to upload the video to facebook with a privacy setting as public. I want to then retrieve the stored video Id and upload it to my server.

My question is is this possible with the current Facebook SDK? I know that I can set the video privacy as public but I am unsure whether or not the SDK will return the video ID. Has anyone had any experience with this? Also will I need to ask for extended permissions to set the video privacy?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may access a user's video data given the `user_videos` extended permission.

**Reference**: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/

From there, you will be able to access properties such as `id`, `embed_html` and `source` that may be applicable to your goals.

**Reference**: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/video/

Enjoy and good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the links. The app in question allows the user to apply special effects to the video before uploading to Facebook. My goal would be to only store the id of the video that the user has edited. I am wondering if by sending a video as a POST if the response will return the id of the uploaded video?

Comment: The only way to retrieve video data is through a user's authentication process (so in this case, you cannot do a reverse lookup using the video itself - only with the user's JSON data).